# What are additions in Swagger 2 over Swagger?

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am implementing swagger for REST layer documentation. Now swaggerfox has come up with swagger2. I am not able to distinguish new changes in **swagger 2 than swagger**. I have very plain simple documentation requirement.  Is there any reference for that?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found following table useful enough to document major improments in swagger 2 over swagger from [here.](https://swagger.io/swagger-2-0-tooling-released/)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite broad, but you can see the changes in all swagger components in [Official Swagger 2.0 Announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/pJaBY4GzY68):

> We've released a new version of swagger-js, swagger-ui, swagger-core,
>   swagger-parser, swagger-codegen and the validator-badge. These include
>   various enhancements to the previous milestone releases (described in
>   the release notes), but notable features are YAML support as a
>   first-class citizen, support for external refs, composition and so
>   much more.